# Storing text file into mysql using Tkinter

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tkinter, phpmyadmin

I am trying to make GUI where there is upload button and when i click that file(text) it should be saved in database(mysql).

Am unable to save text file into database. Tried many things still not getting please help. Am new and learning tkinter first time.

I have tried this but not useful, So if any other idea on it please help.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
root = Tk()
import os



def UploadAction(event=None):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    pathlabel.config(text=filename)



    file = open(filename)
    file_data = file.read()
    file.close()
    file_name = os.path.basename(filename)
    file1=open(file_name,'w+')

    file1.writelines(file_data)




button = Button(root, text='Upload', command=UploadAction)
button.pack()


pathlabel = Label(root)
pathlabel.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

This code showing path but not getting how to save this file into database.

my database name is : fileupload
my table name is : configfile

Comment: try using sqllite3

Comment: You're asking about saving to a database but there's no database code in your question. Have you worked through a tutorial to learn how to use mysql?

Comment: @InfinityTM i want to use mysql

Comment: sqllite3 is a version of mysql in python

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes I know there is no database because i am not getting how to do. Need help, if u know please help me with this

Comment: stackoverflow isn't a tutorial service. There are plenty of tutorials on the internet. For example, https://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-mysql/

Comment: @InfinityTM that is also welcome if u have something related to sqlite

Comment: Get all you want here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-sqlite/

Comment: @InfinityTM is there something related to tkinter and file upload

Comment: @InfinityTM `sqlite3` is not `MySQL` in Python.

Comment: seriously??????